# Как правильно скачивать картинки с помощью curl php

Tags: curl, php

Здавствуйте, есть такая задача,- необходимо скачать множество картинок с сервера, но так, как картинок много скрипту не хватает времени на выполнение.
Пробовал скачивать с помощью мульти курл, но тут тоже косяк, бывает что картинка не полностью скачивается и сохраняется в не читаемом виде.
Функция file_get_contents работает быстрее чем curl, но мне нужно еще получать размер изображения и подключаться по фтп, поэтому для меня тоже не подходит. 
На данный момент скачивание изображений у меня реализовано так;

1. подготавливаю список изображений
       и сохраняю в файлике
2. начинаю скачивать, перезаписываю
       файлик - удаляя из него скаченное
       изображение

Если все скачалось удаляю файлик
Если выполнение скрипта оборвалось, при повторном запуске скачиваю изображения из списка в файлике.
Неудобство заключается в том, что приходиться долго качать и многократно запускать скрипт пока все не скачается, может есть более лучшее решение?

Comment: ssh есть? Запускайте из консоли.

Comment: серверов может быть много, и не на каждом будет ssh. Пытаюсь делать загрузку через сокеты, интересует, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы скрипт не отваливался по таймауту пока грузятся картинки?

Comment: Да, конечно есть. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @Валентин Жуков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Я использовал такую конструкцию:

```
if (preg_match("/http/",$url_files)){  
    $ch = curl_init($url_files);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);  
    $out = curl_exec($ch);  
    $image_sv = 'путь_куда_вы_сохраняете_картинку'.$nm.'.jpg';  
    $img_sc = file_put_contents($image_sv, $out);  
    curl_close($ch);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует еще такой метод.
Это подобие того, как вам ответил ggLike

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [mcurl](https://github.com/KhristenkoYura/mcurl)

```
use MCurl\Client;

$urls = array(
    'ht tp://cs1-38v4.vk-cdn.net/p13/cdfeaeaf00705d.mp3',
    'ht tp://cs1-32v4.vk-cdn.net/p2/5c0972b283ee17.mp3',
);
$save_path = '/tmp';

$client = new Client();

do {
    while ($client->has()) {
        $result = $client->next();
        // Пересохраняем рисунок с ошибкой
        if ($result->hasError()) {
            $urls[] = $result->options[CURLOPT_URL];
        }
    }

    foreach($urls as $url) {
        $file = $save_path . '/'. basename($url);
        $client->add([
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_FILE => fopen($file, 'w'),
        ]);
    }
    $urls = [];

} while($client->run() || $client->has());
```